# Trigger to decrement inventory

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following snippet of an ER-diagram.

Whenever "order_item" is updated (i.e. when an item has been added to a 'shopping cart'), I want to decrement "Quantity" in the table "itemsinstock".

I know the syntax of a trigger (well, MySQL can also generate it) but I don't know how to do it. "order_item" needs to read ItemID from "itemsinstock" and based on that ID, it needs to decrement the quantity for that specific item. Is this possible?

Edit:
This is what I have now:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER  
`orderdb`.`itemsinstock_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `order_item` 
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN UPDATE itemsinstock 
SET Quantity = Quantity - order_item.itemQuantity WHERE itemID = ItemID; END
```

It gives me an error with "order_item.itemQuantity" .... It worked with "-1" but obviously I want it to decrement based on how many "itemQuantity" is. How do I do this?

[image: Snippet of ER diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER  
`orderdb`.`itemsinstock_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `order_item` 
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
   UPDATE itemsinstock 
   SET Quantity = Quantity - NEW.itemQuantity WHERE itemID = NEW.id; 
END
```

notice how order_item (which isn't defined) is being replaced by NEW which represents the row that was inserted. Also as a side note since this is a single statement you don't need begin end blocks

Comment: It seems to work better but your solution has a rather odd issue.

It decrements the other items too even though they don't share the same itemID.  It's rather strange since  the itemID is different?

Comment: Sorry I seem to have copied over a mistake from the original code. The itemId in the where clause also needs to be checked against NEW

Comment: Because in the original query where itemid = itemid is always true. My appologies for not noticing this.

Comment: Ahh! Lovely! Thanks a bunch :) You really helped me out, man. Cheers :)

Comment: glad to have been of help. All the best with your project.